# C# Fiddlercore can not read https response body

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

I have created demo app to read all response body. It is working successfully for HTTP response, But NOT HTTPS. It returns "Untrusted Connection". How to read HTTPS response.

This is code that i am using:

```
 Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
 {
    oS.bBufferResponse = true;
 };

 Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
 {
    String body = oS.GetResponseBodyAsString();
 };

 Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = false;

 if (!CertMaker.rootCertExists())
 {
     if (!CertMaker.createRootCert())
     {
         throw new Exception("Unable to create cert for FiddlerCore.");
     }
 }

 Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);
```

Comment: "Untrusted Connection" sounds for me like the SSL certificate of the server you are trying to connect to is not trusted. Make sure the server uses a valid SSL certificate or set `IgnoreServerCertErrors=true`.

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddler application itself you have to go in and set it up to do HTTPS under options.  This involves installing a certificate on your system to be able to do this.  You may want to do this manually from the application to start - then look at how you can automate it later through the API.

Comment: I did as you said in the fiddler application itself, but nothing happens, the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause of your problems, but that Startup overload is not recommended in the Fiddler documentation. I think you're supposed to use startup flags:

```
FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
```

In the code I run I have also added it to trusted certs

```
if (!CertMaker.rootCertIsTrusted())
{
    if (!CertMaker.trustRootCert())
        throw new Exception("...");
}
```